# Ruby double slash gsub issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a simple text file with content:

```
   patent-inv
```

I'm going to replace **patent-inv** with **part1\\part2**

I did it in such way:

```
source_file = IO.read("#{Rails.root}/my_userdata/1.txt")
source_file.gsub!('<<<patent-inv>>>', "part1\\\\part2")             
File.open("#{Rails.root}/my_userdata/2.txt", "wb") {|f| f.write source_file }
```

But in file I got: 
part1\part2

I tried several ways, but I got the same result:

```
source_file.gsub!('<<<patent-inv>>>', "part1\\\\part2") => "part1\part2"
source_file.gsub!('<<<patent-inv>>>', "part1\\\part2") => "part1\part2"
source_file.gsub!('<<<patent-inv>>>', "part1\\part2") => "part1\part2"
```

Could Anyone help me find out this strange behavior?

Comment: **as Matz said:** backslashes have special escape meaning in strings, so you need to
double slashes.  In addition, backslashes have special meaning in
gsub/sub replacement strings, so you need to double again.  That is
the reason you need 4 backslashes for each single backslash in a
replacement.  It's weird but it's spec for long time.  I don't think
we can change this behavior.  You can use block instead, e.g.  **printf "b".gsub(/b/){'\\'}**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works for me.  Have you tried it in the terminal?  It could be unescaped when you output the result.

```
> a = "<<<patent-inv>>>"
> a.gsub("<<<patent-inv>>>", "part1\\\\part2")    
=> "part1\\part2"
```

You can see how the output varies between `puts` and `p`

```
> puts a
part1\part2
> p a
"part1\\part2"
> puts a.inspect
"part1\\part2"
```

**EDIT**  Here is the output displayed as you want it.

```
1.9.2-p290 :037 > a.gsub!("<<<patent-inv>>>", "part1\\\\\\part2")
 => "part1\\\\part2" 
> p a
"part1\\\\part2"
 => "part1\\\\part2" 
> puts a
part1\\part2
 => nil
```

We know that 4 backslashes when changed equals 2 backslashes when unescaped.  So 4 backslashes need to be generated AFTER the substitution for it to be displayed correctly.

Comment: Yes, in console it works. But why does It work? **source_file.gsub!('patent-inv', "part1\\part2") => "part1\\part2"**. But Why??

Comment: Because when you output, "\\" is unescaped to "\".  See my edits.

Comment: Ok, it's clear for me with console. But my question was about writing to file. Why is there unexpected behavior?

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** Correcting my answer as a whole. I was mislead by the fact that `puts` escapes the `\` symbol when it is output and thus I thought I achieved the goal without actually being there. However now I have it working. See my experiment:

```
> str = "patent-inv"
=> "patent-inv"
> str.gsub!('patent-inv', "part1\\\\part2")
=> "part1\\part2"
> str.chars.each { |t| puts t }
p
a
r
t
1
\
p
a
r
t
2
=> "part1\\part2"
> str = "patent-inv"
=> "patent-inv"
> str.gsub!('patent-inv', "part1\\\\\\part2")
=> "part1\\\\part2"
> str.chars.each { |t| puts t }
p
a
r
t
1
\
\
p
a
r
t
2
=> "part1\\\\part2"
```

Basically I am using `str.chars.each { |t| puts t }` to see what characters are actually contained in the string. As you can see the correct pattern to use is `part1\\\\\\part2`.

Comment: In console it works and it doesn't work at the same time: **source_file.gsub!('patent-inv', "part1\\part2")** gives me the same result **"part1\\part2"**. But Why??

Comment: I have corrected my answer as it was totally wrong. I was mislead interpreting the output. Actually the string contained only a single `\` but puts escaped it and it appeared double.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
source_file.gsub!('<<<patent-inv>>>', "part1\\\\\\\\part2") => "part1\part2"
```

=)

Comment: Maybe source_file.gsub!('<<<patent-inv>>>', "part1\\\\\\\\\\\\\part2") => "part1\part2" ??? ))

Comment: actually, I tested my code: read from file and write to another. When you gsub \\\\\\\\ translates to \\\\, when you write \\\\ translates to \\